# How do I convert a date from a datepicker input to a certain format in PHP?

Tags: php, date

I am new to PHP. I have a date string from a date-picker input field. But when I try to convert date string it into a date, I get an unexpected date.

Sample error:

- If input (`$datestamp`) contains `24/01/2016`, then it becomes `$date = '70/01/01`  [error]

Here is the PHP code:

```
<?php  
    $datestring = (isset($_POST['datetimepicker1'])) ? $_POST['datetimepicker1'] : "not";

    $date = date("y/d/m", strtotime($datestring));      
    echo   $datestring; 
    echo   var_dump($date);     
?>
```

**updates:**
here is my datepicker code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({format:"DD/MM/YYYY", useCurrent: false });
        });         
 </script>
```

Please help me fix this. Is this a format problem? I need to insert the date into an Oracle database.

Comment: Do a `var_dump($datestring);` please--does it say `"not"` or what does it say? What format would you like the `$date` in? `<YEAR>/<DATE>/<MONTH>` or `<DATE>/<YEAR>/<MONTH>` or what?

Comment: `1970-01-01` is the date of the `0` unix timestamp (the UNIX Epoch). This usually means that `strtotime()` returned an error.

Comment: Thanks @Will.var_dump($datestring); showing string '24/01/2016' (length=10).thanks

Answer (score 2):

According to jQuery, the datepicker default format is the following:
`mm/dd/yy`.

So, you can try this (in order to convert the `$datestring` to the `y/m/d` format):

```
<?php
$datestring = '24/01/2016';
list($day, $month, $year) = explode('/', $datestring);
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Ymd', $year . $month . $day);
echo $date->format('y/m/d');
?>
```

You can also change the datepicker:

```
var date = $('#datepicker').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy' }).val();
```

Comment: thanks @Kevin but it is not converting.

Answer (score 2):

Please replace date function with below code. I have used explode to extract year, month and date separately, pass it to strtotime function.

```
<?php  
    $datestring = (isset($_POST['datetimepicker1'])) ? $_POST['datetimepicker1'] : "not";
    $date_arr = explode('/',$datestring);
    $date = date("Y/m/d", strtotime($date_arr[2].$date_arr[1].$date_arr[0]));
    echo   $datestring; 
    echo   var_dump($date);     
?>
```

Comment: thanks @Sashant Pardeshi. but it is no working.it get reset to 1-JAN-1970

Comment: very sorry for issue, could u plz provide value received in post $_POST['datetimepicker1']. May be some issue der.

Answer (score 1):

Use this code

```
<?php  
$datestring = (isset($_POST['datetimepicker1'])) ? $_POST['datetimepicker1'] : "not";
$datestring = str_replace('/', '-', $datestring);
$date = date("y/d/m", strtotime($datestring));      
echo   $datestring; 
echo   var_dump($date);
```

?>

Just replace('/') to  ('-') before passing to strtotime function. Sometime ('/') not work.

Comment: thanks @Sonu R . but it is no working.it get reset to 1-JAN-1970

Comment: Replace your code _$datestring = (isset($_POST['datetimepicker1'])) ? $_POST['datetimepicker1'] : "not";_  with this  _$datestring = "24/01/2016";_ for just test and check. may be your datetimepicker1 is wrong.

Comment: thanks @Sonu R. i did echo   var_dump($datestring); and got his string '24/01/2016' (length=10)